# Xamarin Forms- Text for label should be updated in each app status

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have programmed an app that has a timer. I need is when the timer was started then in each app status (OnStart, OnResume, OnSleep) should run and the remaining time is displayed in a label until really the time was elapsed. Practical example: The user opens the app sets the timer for 10 min then closes the app with home button or return button. After three minutes he opens the app and the label is set to 7 minutes and is continuously elapsed by the second. He can see every time he opens the app how the remaining time is running backwards by seconds. My problem is that the text from label is not always updatet (UI is not updatet) as it runs backwards.How can i fix this? Thank you all

Here is my Code from MainPage

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WifiTimer
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int minutes = 0;
        public int hours = 0;


        private static TimeSpan restTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

        private string displayRemainTime = restTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

        private Task task;

        private bool cancel;

        public string RemainingTime
        {
            get => displayRemainTime;
            set
            {
                displayRemainTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(value);

            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        PickersLists pickers = new PickersLists();

       
        public MainPage()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadPickerHours();
            LoadPickerMinutes();
            BindingContext = this;
            LabelCountdown.Text = displayRemainTime;

          
            if (task != null)
            {
                ActivateElements(false);
            }
        }


        public void DisableWifi()
        {

            DependencyService.Get<IWifiManager>().CheckWifi();

        }


        public void StartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (task == null)
            {
                
                StartCountdown(hours, minutes);
         

            }         
        }


        public void StartCountdown(int hours, int min)
        {
          
            var M = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(min);
            var H = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
            var zero = TimeSpan.FromHours(0) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            restTime = H.Add(M);

            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

            if (cancel == true)
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
     
            task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
               
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                   {
                       DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StartService();
                       restTime -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                       displayRemainTime = restTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

                       LabelCountdown.Text = RemainingTime;

                       if (cancel == true)
                       {
                           PickerHours.SelectedIndex = 0;
                           PickerMinutes.SelectedIndex = 0;
                           ActivateElements(true);
                           LabelCountdown.Text = zero.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                           cancel = false;
                           task = null;                
                           return false;
                       }

                       if (restTime == zero)
                       {
                           DisableWifi();
                           DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StopService();
                           PickerHours.SelectedIndex = 0;
                           PickerMinutes.SelectedIndex = 0;
                           ActivateElements(true);
                           task = null;
                           return false; //false timer wird ausgeschaltet
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                           {
                               ActivateElements(false);
                           });


                           return true; //true timer wird wiederholt
                       }
                   });

           }, token);
        }

        public void ActivateElements(bool visible)
        {
            StartButton.IsEnabled = visible;
            LabelHours.IsEnabled = visible;
            DelimiterTime.IsEnabled = visible;
            LabelMinutes.IsEnabled = visible;
            PickerHours.IsEnabled = visible;
            PickerMinutes.IsEnabled = visible;
        }


        public void StopButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (task != null)
            {
                cancel = true;
            }
        }



        public void PickerHours_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedHours = PickerHours.Items[PickerHours.SelectedIndex];

            var selectedHoursToInt = int.Parse(selectedHours);

            hours = selectedHoursToInt;
        }


        public void PickerMinutes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedMinutes = PickerMinutes.Items[PickerMinutes.SelectedIndex];

            var selectedMinutesToInt = int.Parse(selectedMinutes);

            minutes = selectedMinutesToInt;
        }

   
        public void LoadPickerHours()
        {
            PickerHours.ItemsSource = pickers.hoursList;
            PickerHours.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }


        public void LoadPickerMinutes()
        {
            PickerMinutes.ItemsSource = pickers.minutesList;
            PickerMinutes.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my App Class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace WifiTimer
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
           
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "the time is not always displayed" - what does this mean?  Are you saying it works perfectly but the UI is not updating?  Or is the timer itself not working?

Comment: Helo Jason , yes the UI is not update. I mean the text in Label is not updated by the second. The variable in my code is "RemainingTime ". Thank you very much

Comment: @Yves Your app will be suspended when it enters the background (`OnSleep` in Forms), for android you will need to implement an Android based Foregrounded Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: Thank you SushiHangover. Where must I implement the foreground service ? In Main Page or in App class ? I have already implemented a foreground service. Please show under Device.StartTimer() Method. There is. Thank you

Comment: @Yves Maybe you can provide your simple sample at github, I will download your sample to test. It is better to understand your problem.

Comment: Hello Cherry Bu,

thank you for your helpfulness and sorry for the late reply. How can I find you on github. My nickname there is : dersharky 
I can unlock the the repository there 
Thanks to you

Comment: @Yves you just need to provide your simple sample at github or onedrive, provide the link here, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: @Cherry Bu here is the link from github.     
 https://github.com/dersharky/WifiTimer                                                                  
 The Code work well but if you press the return button than the Label Text from 
 remaining time is not more updating. Thank you realy very much for the help.

Comment: @Yves I download your sample to test, and there is one problem about `Notification`, the namespace  name `Notification` could not be found.